# CLLocationManager weird behaviour on IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, mapkit, cllocationmanager

Sometimes `CLLocationManager` doesn't give call back to my app. It neither call `didUpdateLocation` or failure delegate method. I am unable to understand why such behaviour of `LocationManager`. This thing happen rarely but still happen and break the functionality of location. If anybody can help me regarding this that will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the location manager having some kind of issue when an application goes into the background.  It could stop updating for 5 to 20 minutes. But after that it would return to better, if not quite normal, behavior.